# How to create quadrilateral (rhombus shape) with specific degree?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-shapes

How can I create a quadrilateral with css, when I know which degree each corner has.

I already tried to recreate a quadrilateral I have with transform and skew.

However, this does not work really well.

This is what I try to archive.

[image: CSS Quadrilateral diamond shape]

The exact requirements are:

A div with this as background in one color. On the image are just construction lines. It should be a solid quadrilateral with these angles.

This was my first idea:

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(27.5deg, 62.5deg)
transform-origin: top center;
```

Comment: Above picture doesn't seems to be a square. A square should have 4 equal sides, all sides are equal in length, every angle is 90 degree.

Comment: I am sorry. Square was the translation of "Viereck". I am not a native english speaker. So maybe I meant "quadrilateral"

Comment: I can see that left and right angle is 53 degree each. How much is the bottom angle? I'm asking because it seems overwritten & not clear. Is it 250 degree?

Comment: 62.5. And the sum of course is 125. They are not 100% exact, because I extracted them from an image. Of course the sum of all angles (If you split the quadrilateral into 4 triangles) needs to be equal 180. 26 + 90 + 62.5 =~ 180

Comment: I totally forgot, the punctuation in english is different. Updated the image with better readable numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider multiple background to achieve this where I simply need to find the width/height of the element. Based on your illustration we have this:

[image: CSS rhombus shape]

From this we can have the following formula:

```
tan(alpha) = W/H
```

and

```
tan(beta/2) = H/W
```

We only need to use one of them and you will notice that there isn't one solution which is logical as you simply need to keep a ratio between `H` and `W` and the width of our element will simply be `2*W` and its height `2*H`.

Since `H/W` is also the same as `2*H/2*W` we can simply consider that `width = tan(alpha)*height`

```css
.box {
  height:var(--h);
  width:calc(1.92098213 * var(--h)); /* tan(62.5)xH */
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,red 50%) top left,
   linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49%,red 50%) bottom left,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49%,red 50%) top right,
   linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 49%,red 50%) bottom right;
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--h:50px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--h:100px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--h:200px;"></div>
```

You can adjust the gradient if you want only borders:

```css
.box {
  height:var(--h);
  width:calc(1.92098213 * var(--h)); /* tan(62.5)xH */
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,red 50%,transparent calc(50% + 2px)) top left,
   linear-gradient(to top    right,transparent 49%,red 50%,transparent calc(50% + 2px)) bottom left,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left ,transparent 49%,red 50%,transparent calc(50% + 2px)) top right,
   linear-gradient(to top    left ,transparent 49%,red 50%,transparent calc(50% + 2px))  bottom right;
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--h:50px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--h:100px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--h:200px;"></div>
```

---

Using transform the idea is to rely on `rotateX()` in order to visually decrease the height to keep the formula defined previously. So we start by having `Width=height` (a square) then we rotate like below:

[image]

This is a view from the side. The green is our rotated element and the red the initial one. It's clear that we will see the height `H1` after performing the rotation and we have this formula:

```
cos(angle) = H1/H
```

And we aleardy have `tan(alpha)=W/H1` so we will have

```
cos(angle) = W/(H*tan(alpha))
```

and `H=W` since we defined a square initially so we will have `cos(angle) = 1/tan(alpha) --> angle = cos-1(1/tan(alpha))`

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
  margin:50px;
  transform:rotateX(58.63017731deg) rotate(45deg); /* cos-1(0.52056)*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

We can also apply the same logic using `rotateY()` to update the width in the situation where you will have beta bigger than `90deg` and alpha smaller than `45deg`. In this case we will have `W < H` and the `rotateX()` won't help us.

The math can easily confirm this. when `alpha` is smaller than `45deg` `tan(alpha)` will be smaller than `1` thus `1/tan(alpha)` will bigger than `1` and `cos` is only defined between `[-1 1]` so there is no angle we can use with `rotateX()`

Here is an animation to illustrate:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  margin:50px;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
.alt {
  animation:change-alt 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(45deg)}
  to{  transform:rotateX(90deg) rotate(45deg)}
}
@keyframes change-alt {
  from{transform:rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}
  to{  transform:rotateY(90deg) rotate(45deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box alt">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This nearly perfect. At least it answers the question perfectly. However, is there a way to use `border-radius` or imitate it?

Comment: @Noim I am adding another way ;) give me 5min

Comment: @Noim check the update, with the new method you can add radius easily ;)

Answer (score 2):

In various way you can do it. Since you're trying to use degree value so here I can give you an example: first of you can take four lines for your rectangle and rotate them as you want with degree value. Here is what I mean:

```
<div class="top_line"></div>
<div class="right_line"></div>
<div class="bottom_line"></div>
<div class="left_line"></div>
```

Css

```
.top_line { height: 170px; border-right: 1px solid yellow; transform: rotate(50deg);
  position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 400px; transform-origin: 0% 130%; }
.right_line {height: 140px; border-right: 1px solid red; transform: rotate(130deg);
  position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 500px; transform-origin: 0% 50%; }
.bottom_line { height: 140px; border-right: 1px solid green; transform: rotate(130deg);
  position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 400px; transform-origin: -1800% 80%; }
.left_line { height: 140px; border-right: 1px solid blue; transform: rotate(50deg);
  position: absolute; top: 140px; left: 400px; }
```

[Here is the live preview](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/gEovYO)

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you made and how, however, it does not really fit my goal (At least I think). I try to recreate a solid surface with this shape, not exactly the construction lines from the image.